# Box.net api, reading source of a file with a download file

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, get, box-api

Currently I am working on a Web Application (as a hobby) for editing "In the Cloud" files. The API I am using is the box.net one, and now I need to get the source code of files. There is no function for that, only a download GET command. How can I use the download command to get the source of files on a web application? I don't have a lot of server space, so...

Answer (score 1):

This is Jeremy from Box.net (the Platform Manager).  Are you working stricly with Javascript (server-side Javascript, perhaps)?  Or can you handle operations in PHP, Java, etc on your server?  With a server-side language, you can obtain a file from another server more easily.

For instance, a common means of obtaining a file via PHP can be found at http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxticker/ajaxticker2.shtml  (we're familiar with developers using the file_get_contents method, or fget on a Box API download URL)